# Visual Studio 2015 Publishing Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, publishing, n-tier-architecture

I am able to build the solution and run in `Debug` mode but when I try to publish to my local `inetpub` directory it fails!?!?!

Here is the build output (showing that all is well)

[image: build output]

Then, here is the publish output:

[image: the failed publish output]

Here is the class and reference in question. This proves and shows that all is legit.

[image]

Can you please help me out here.

Comment: add this reference to release folder and try again.if it is not publish again,add dll to project and go to properties on this file and set Copy to output directory to always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First build your solution in Release mode and check there are no
  errors.
- Also make sure that in your BL Project Bin\Release folder,
  DAL project DLL is copied.
- Start Publish again.